# Change checked state with Image

Tags: c#, winforms

I use this code, bound to `PictureBox`'s `Click` event, to change the image when the `PictureBox` is clicked.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //domanda else if
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.On;
                checkBox1.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Off;
                checkBox1.Checked = false;
            }
        }
```

It works, but if I have the "on" image in the `PictureBox`, clicking it does not change the image, it is still the "on" image.
I tried this code but it does not work for me:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
    if (pictureBox1.Image == Properties.Resources.On)
                    {                        
                        checkBox1.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {                            
                        checkBox1.Checked = false;
                    }
}
```

I need image on = checkedbox Checked
image off = checkedbox not Checked

Comment: "but not work for me" is not helpful. Please explain.

Comment: nothing.. the picturebox state not changed, no error on code

Comment: The first code should work, I can't understand these words of yours `It works, but if I have the "on" image in the PictureBox, clicking it does not change the image, it is still the "on" image`? Any more clarification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `pictureBox1.Image == Properties.Resources.On` you're checking if they're equal to the same reference. The answer is that they're not, so even though the images are the same, the actual references are not. Instead you can use the PictureBox's [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property to store the current image data. For example

```
 if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
 {
     pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.On;
     pictureBox1.Tag = "ON";
     checkBox1.Checked = true;            
 }
 else
 {
     pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Off;
     pictureBox1.Tag = "OFF";
     checkBox1.Checked = false;
 }
```

You can then read that Tag when you want to see what image it has

```
if (pictureBox1.Tag.ToString() == "ON")
    checkBox1.Checked = true;
else                            
    checkBox1.Checked = false;
```

As a side note, the `Tag` property holds `object` types so you don't have to store and compare strings, you can add enums for example. (Although in this case a string should suffice).