# Check state of every picturebox together on submit

Tags: c#, winforms, state, picturebox

Here is my question:
Im making a booking cinema system in c#, windows form
Let's say i have 5 columns of 5 rows of pictureboxes that on form load get their value, avaliable or not from the database.
The user then click on the seat he wants (and the image of the pictuebox change) and press a submit button.
How i can check the image of every picturebox (to determine if he want this seat or not) together?
I can do something like this

```
if (picturebox11.image=="seatchecked"){seats[]+=11;}
if (picturebox12...
```

But im wondering if there is another faster way to do it. (the position of the pictureboxes is fixed if that helps)

I have done this so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<PictureBox> pb = new List<PictureBox>();
            pb.Add(seat11);
            pb.Add(seat12);
            pb.Add(seat13);
            pb.Add(seat14);
            pb.Add(seat15);
            pb.Add(seat21);
            pb.Add(seat22);
            pb.Add(seat23);
            pb.Add(seat24);
            pb.Add(seat25);
            pb.Add(seat31);
            pb.Add(seat32);
            pb.Add(seat33);
            pb.Add(seat34);
            pb.Add(seat35);
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

                pb[i].Click += pictureBox_Click;
            }
        }
             void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.pictureBox.Image = ArgyroCinema.Properties.Resources.seatred;     
}
```

Comment: What's that `seats[]+=11;`? index an array and add 11?

Comment: yes you are right i have it wrong, let's just say that i store the seat on a array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store each PictureBox in a list and iterate through them. Also, when the user selects/deselects a seat, change the `Tag` property of the PictureBox as, at the moment, you're trying to compare a string to an `Image` (picturebox11.Image returns an `Image` object).

```
List<PictureBox> pb = new List<PictureBox>();
pb.Add(pictureBox1);
pb.Add(pictureBox2);
//etc..
```

Alternatively, you can use the [methods suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630391/get-all-controls-of-a-specific-type) to get all `PictureBox` objects in your form to save you having to type it out above.

Then just iterate through them and read their `Tag` property. In this case I've used `true` to represent that they want the seat but `Tag` is an object type, so you can use whatever type you like.

```
foreach(PictureBox p in allPictureBoxes)
{        
    if((bool)p.Tag == true)
    {
       //seat wanted
    }
    else
    {
       //seat not wanted
    }
}
```

Update from comments

```
void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PictureBox pb = sender as PictureBox;
   if(pb != null)
      pb.Image = ArgyroCinema.Properties.Resources.seatred;     
}
```

Comment: i can add mouseenter and mouseleave events in all of them together with those solutions? im having hard time figuring out how

Comment: Yes you can but it depends on how you're creating the PictureBox. Are you creating them in the designer or in code?

Comment: i guess i can create and place them in the code if that will help me to avoid some code, if you can please give me an example of how to create ,set an image from the project database, place it in the form and add those events

Comment: See the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606819/creating-numerous-pictureboxes-by-code-only-one-is-visible) to show you how to create them in code. After creating them, simply add them to a list (`myList.Add(mainSprite)`). You can attach the click event handler as [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17907655/187697).

Comment: i have edit my first post, i dont know how to set up the event for every picture box (this.pictureBox.Image doesnt work)
Also some pictureboxes must be locked if there are already booked. i should use enabled.false? i have to put it last in the code or it doesnt matter?

Comment: That seems fine although you might want to use `i < pb.Count` instead in case the size of the list changes. Add an `if` check to see if that PB should be locked, in which case, you can set the `Enabled` property to false like you said. Putting it last in the `for` loop would work.

Comment: im getting this error:Error 1 'ArgyroCinema.FormRes' does not contain a definition for 'pictureBox' and no extension method 'pictureBox' accepting a first argument of type 'ArgyroCinema.FormRes' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Exoskeletor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ArgyroCinema\ArgyroCinema\FormRes.cs 51 20 ArgyroCinema

Comment: @CDrosos - Ah sorry, I missed your `pictureBox_Click` event. Cast the `sender` to a PictureBox and use that. (See my updated answer).

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to create a new list every time the button is clicked? If you want to do it as a one-off then move it outside the button's click event.

Comment: so far so good. now im trying to select deselect the avaliable seat on click. im trying to do it this way:
if (pb.Image.ToString == "seatblue2")
                {
                    pb.Image = ArgyroCinema.Properties.Resources.seatblue;
                }
                else {
                    pb.Image = ArgyroCinema.Properties.Resources.seatblue2;
                }
what am i doing again wrong?

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460419/change-checked-state-with-image). (Basically, use the `Tag` property to determine the seat colour instead of the `Image` property).

Comment: Thanx work amazing. one last question. is there a way to do something like this:
int booked_set[]={11,12};
for (i=0;i<30;i++)
seat[].enabled=false

Comment: What are you trying to do? Disable only 11 and 12?

Comment: yes but i think i will just do this if seats_booked=="11" then seat11.enabled=false. i just have to do it 20 times

Comment: This might be easier. Have an array (like you do) that stores the ones you want disabled. Then in your loop, do this  `if (booked_set.Contains(i))
         seat[i].Enabled=false`. That checks if `i` is in your array. If it is, then disable that particular seat.

Comment: thanks but i think i cant do that because the first number is the line number and the second number is the seat number

Comment: Ah okay, I misunderstood what that represented.