# Passing control's MouseClick event to its container

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mouseclick-event

I'll try to be concise but comrehensible. I have a dynamic 2-dimensional array of PictureBox elements, and they're all added to the same form via:

```
this.Controls.Add(PictureBoxArray[i,j]);
```

Now I've designed an algorithm that would determine which of these PBs are clicked, but I've placed it in the ParentForm_MouseClick method. And now I've reached a paradox. The algorithm I've created returns the proper output, but the ParentForm_MouseClick method is called only when I click on the empty space in the Form, not when I click on PictureBoxes. So my question is - how can I invoke ParentForm_MouseClick method when users click anywhere in the form i.e. can I somehow override PictureBoxes' MouseClick events so that ParentForm_MouseClick is invoked instead?

EDIT: This just occured to me, could I create a custom PictureBoxClass Class that extends the .NET one and just override the MouseClick() event to invoke a method I've previously written?

Comment: why not just assign a mouse click event to each picturebox? then there isn't any algorithm, you just use the sender of the event

Comment: That is the easiest way. But I've got 8x8 array and as far as I know there isn't a Control.setOnClickEventMethod() in .NET so I'd have to implement it for each one individually.

Comment: You can iterate through the array and attach the event handler.

Comment: There is no good explanation for *why* you need the form's MouseClick event to fire.  There are too many ways to do it to favor one over the other if you don't explain this, none of them particularly pretty.  A very simple way to do this is to set the event handler for the PB's MouseClick event to the form's MouseClick event handler.  They don't *have* to be different methods.

Comment: I applied Hans' as well as keyboardP's solutions. I've attached ParentForm_MouseClick as the event handler for all the PB elements. But take care if you do this to wrap up the method in try/catch block because it would raise an IndexOutOfBoundsException when you click outside the boxes, obviously. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're over-complicating things. If you're going to need to call the code within an event handler from different places, it's a good idea to abstract that out to a different method. You can attach the same event handler to the PictureBoxes which then call that method.

```
for(int i = 0; i < PictureBoxArray.GetLength(0); i++) 
{
    for(int j = 0; j < PictureBoxArray.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        //attach handler
        PictureBoxArray[i,j].Click += pictureBox_Click;
    }
}


void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MyMethod();      
}

void parentForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MyMethod();       
}

private void MyMethod()
{
   //method to be called
}
```